# htaccess dynamic target using regular expressions

Tags: regex, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

Hi I want to create a rule to remove the first directory on the url, see the example:

request url: http://www.example.com/San-Salvador/help

I want to redirect that to

Target url: http://www.example.com/help

the pattern is [base url][city name][directory] and I want to recreate it as this [base url][directory name]

Comment: Can you show us some sample code where you expect the regex to run?

Comment: well the regex is not the main problem, the main problem is write a rule using htaccess

Comment: What happens when you enter `http://www.example.com/help` in browser?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a general regex which should work:

```
^(http:\/\/www\.example\.com\/)(.*\/)(.*)
```

Each term in parentheses is a *group* which will potentially match an input string.  For the input string:

```
http://www.example.com/San-Salvador/help
```

here are the matching groups:

```
http://www.example.com/
San-Salvador/
help
```

The groups you want to *retain* are the first and third ones, i.e. `http://www.example.com/` and `help` to give you `http://www.example.com/help`

You can explore this regex [**here at Regex 101**](https://regex101.com/r/hS6zP5/2).

Comment: thanks, now I just need to figure out how to put that in variables to use on the htaccess

Comment: @Jose If you can me some context I will try to give you code you can use in WordPress.

Comment: well I move from a custom cms to wordpress and I dont want to loose all the SEO because I change the structure of the site, the old site was written on asp.net mvc and they did the handling of the urls in code. I'm trying to replicate that on wordpress. in the asp.net project they parse the url and redirect it to a new url without changing the url show in the browser. I hope that make sense

Comment: You need to show us code, not a description of code.

Comment: RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteRule    ^/San-Salvador/help?$    /help    [NC,L] this is my current code on the htaccess it does work but I will have to create a rule for each city and I want it to be more dynamic

Answer (score 0):

For the most part this is a rule that you can use to remove the city. However your code will need to handle what happens after the redirected URL is requested. Meaning what is displayed when this is called `http://www.example.com/help`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(?:[^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks this solution does work but it change the url in the browser, is there a way to write this http://www.example.com/San-Salvador/help on the address bar,redirect to here http://www.example.com/help, but don't change the address on the address bar

Comment: @JoseManuelOjeda you should be able to just remove the 301 redirect and the full URL. See my update.